# JavaFX generate blank single color Image

Tags: image, javafx

I would like to generate an image with just one color on it, to use for creating maps for PhongMaterials.  Something like

`Image generateImage(int width, int height, double red, double green, double blue, double opacity);`

What do I need to do to make this?  While I'd prefer to make this purely procedurally, if there's a way to do this by giving it a blank white image like https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/fff.png and changing its color, I would be okay with that too.  I thought about just generating a URL and getting the image directly from that website, but I can't be dependent on internet connection for this to work (and besides, that website doesn't handle transparent images).

Comment: If it's a solid single color, do you actually have a need for the width and height here? E.g. in an `ImageView` you can just scale a 1 pixel by 1 pixel image up to the desired size, saving both computational time and memory

Comment: That works too!  How do you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return an image as you specify, you can do:

```
public Image generateImage(int width, int height, double red, double green, double blue, double opacity) {
    WritableImage img = new WritableImage(width, height);
    PixelWriter pw = img.getPixelWriter();

    // Should really verify 0.0 <= red, green, blue, opacity <= 1.0        
    int alpha = (int) (opacity * 255) ;
    int r = (int) (red * 255) ;
    int g = (int) (green * 255) ;
    int b = (int) (blue * 255) ;

    int pixel = (alpha << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b ;
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    Arrays.fill(pixels, pixel);

    pw.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), pixels, 0, width);
    return img ;
}
```

In pretty much any use case (that I can think of), you may as well create an image that is 1 pixel by 1 pixel, and then scale it up on the fly. If this suffices, you can simplify this to

```
public Image generateImage(double red, double green, double blue, double opacity) {
    WritableImage img = new WritableImage(1, 1);
    PixelWriter pw = img.getPixelWriter();

    Color color = Color.color(red, green, blue, opacity);
    pw.setColor(0, 0, color);
    return img ;
}
```

Then, e.g. you can do:

```
Image marshallUniGreen = generateImage(0, 177.0 / 255, 65.0 / 255, 1) ; 
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(marshallUniGreen);
imageView.setFitWidth(300);
imageView.setFitHeight(200);
imageView.setPreserveRatio(false);
```